# How Multi Select in UITableView with UITableViewCellAccessory Checkmark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    { 
    [self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    [self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
    if([self.tableView endEditing:YES])
    { 
       self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init]; 
       NSArray *personels = [[PersonelList sharedList] allPersonel]; 
       Personnel *selectedPersonel = personels[indexPath.row]; 
       _detailViewController.personel = selectedPersonel; 
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:_detailViewController animated:YES];
    }

    }  
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
         return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellSelectionStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 { 
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

                NSArray *selectedRows = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
                NSMutableArray *mySelectedObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
                for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedRows) 
                {
                    NSArray *personels = [[PersonelList sharedList] allPersonel];
                    Personnel *selectedPersonel = personels[indexPath.row];
                    [mySelectedObjects addObject:selectedPersonel];
                    NSLog(@"selection objects: %@",mySelectedObjects);
                }
                [self saveSelects];
                [self.tableView endEditing:YES];

           }

 }
```

I want to multi select in table view editing mode and save
 selected cell in array. this is my code for editing mode but when I tapped checkmark bottom my view navigate in detail view. How can i do this job
?

Comment: show ur did select row method./

Comment: pls update ur question with the code

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I create UIButton in table view cell with table view content size add define block in detail view and implement block in table view did selected row method.

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^actionBlockDetail)(void);
//
@implementation EmployeeViewController
 cell.actionBlock = ^{
        PersonnelCell *strongCell = weakCell;

        self.favP = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        if (searchController.active) {
            strongCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            Personnel *selectedPersonel = self.resultPersonnel[indexPath.row];
            self.detailViewController.personel = selectedPersonel;
            indexP = indexPath;

            if (!self.splitViewController) {
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController
                                                     animated:YES];
                double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    strongCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                });
            }
```